# Get switch type case to int64 - Golang

Tags: go, type-conversion

how can i get type switching for an empty interface to an int64

```
var vari interface{}
vari = 7466
switch v := vari.(type) {
case int64:
    fmt.Println("integer", v)
default:
    fmt.Println("unknown")
}
```

This prints unknown.
It works fine (prints "integer 7466") if i do it for int but not for int64. How can i get int64?

Comment: To put it another way, type assertions (and hence type switches) only assert what type a value _is_, not what you wish it to be.

Answer (score 4):

The literal `7466` is an untyped constant, and in that context, it is interpreted as an `int`, not as an `int64`. So either test the case for `int`, or do:

```
vari = int64(7466)
```

This is because `int` and `int64` are distinct types.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to consider here:

1. You absolutely know that the value assigned to the interface has some **known** integer type. Example:

   ```
    var vari interface{}
    vari = 7466 // could be int64|32|16|8(7466)
    v, ok := vari.(int) // or int64|32|16|8
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("unknown")
        return 0
    }
    return int64(v)
   ```
2. You don't know what the type of the value in the interface is. The reflect package might help you. [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/avcgX7g5HrN)

   ```
    func getInt64(v interface{}) (int64, error) {
        switch reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() {
        case reflect.Int8:
            d, _ := v.(int8)
            return int64(d), nil
        case reflect.Int16:
            d, _ := v.(int16)
            return int64(d), nil
        case reflect.Int32:
            d, _ := v.(int32)
            return int64(d), nil
        case reflect.Int64:
            d, _ := v.(int64)
            return d, nil
        case reflect.Int:
            d, _ := v.(int)
            return int64(d), nil
        // ... tackle uint if needed
        }

        return 0, fmt.Errorf("not interger: %v", v)
    }
   ```